# Android:Text based icons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-fonts

I am working on a project which was developed by another developer.To set icons he has used icon codes like this

```
<string name="icAddress">\ue902</string>
<string name="icAgeGroup">\ue903</string>
```

I generally use icons as as imageview but he has used it as customtextview like this

```
<com.util.CustomTextView
   android:id="@+id/tvIcAddress"
   style="@style/menuIcon"
   android:text="@string/icAddress" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="menuIcon">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/dpSize50</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/appColor</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/bigTextSize</item>
</style>
```

The project has a font file in assets folder and in CustomTextView he has applied that font using setTypeface.I am not getting what's going on here.Now i want to use skype icon in some layout.How would i use it in same fashion.How can i get its icon code.

here is the CustomTextViewFile

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    applyCustomFont(context);
}

private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
    setTypeface(Util.getIns().getCustomFont(context));
 }
}
```

getCustomFont method:

```
public Typeface getCustomFont(Context context) {
    if (customTypeFace == null) {
        customTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "hell.ttf");
        return customTypeFace;
    }
    return customTypeFace;
}
```

Xml code of layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearHistory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dpSize45"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.util.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvIcCaseHistory"
                    style="@style/menuIcon"
                    android:text="@string/icCaseHistory" />

                <com.util.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCaseHistory"
                    style="@style/menuText"
                    android:text="Case History" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dpSize50"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dpSize15"

                android:background="@color/appColor" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearPrescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dpSize45"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.util.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvIcPrescription"
                    style="@style/menuIcon"
                    android:text="@string/icPrescription" />

                <com.util.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPrescription"
                    style="@style/menuText"
                    android:text="Prescription" />

            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

screenshot showing icons:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLNfm.png)

Comment: \ue902 and \ue902 are UTF character not an image. Can you share screen shot.

Comment: i have added the screenshot please take a look.

Comment: Which custom font you used? can you share layout file code.

Comment: have a look at the edited post.

Comment: please add xml file code for which you added screenshot

Comment: xml file added.Added only two rows as other code would be repetitive.

Comment: It is upto you how would prefer skype icon? Bcoz you can either ask from professional designer who would provide character code for required icon using Font Face in this case 'hell.ttf' and then use it in CustomTextView. OR you can get the icon in png format and use it as drawables.

Answer (score 0):

The values,

```
  <string name="icAddress">\ue902</string>
  <string name="icAgeGroup">\ue903</string>
```

are utf encoded characters, and to show that characters he used font in assets folder,
The corresponding character of any utf can be found;
[Here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e902/index.htm)

In your case the customtextview shows the specified character, there should be an image somewhere in your application that is being showed in the layout.

Comment: I searched the whole project for image file but didn't find one.